# Git history rewrite on Bitbucket [remote rejected] HEAD -> branch (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, bitbucket

On Bitbucket, using the Bitbucket web interface, I sync'd a blessed repo with my own private fork in error. I wanted to rewrite history on the blessed repo to bring it back to the correct commit.

I cloned the blessed repo that contained my incorrect commits and locally ran

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

on the branch whose history was screwed up.

This brought the cloned repo back to the commit it was at before I screwed it up.

I then went to push my repo back up to Bitbucket using

```
git push -f origin development
```

but got the following error

```
remote: permission denied to force push branch development
To git@bitbucket.org:blessed-repo/blessed-repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> development (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:blessed-repo/blessed-repo.git'
```

Why did I get this error and how can I make the `git push` work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Bitbucket, it is possible to <s>[limit push powers broken-link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Branch+management#Branchmanagement-Limitpushpowers)</s> [use branch permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-permissions-385912271.html) to prevent users from pushing to a branch directly.

From the above (old, no longer available) docs ...

> Users are free to interact with a branch in their local clone. When
>   they attempt to push to the Bitbucket remote, users who aren't allowed
>   to push to the branch receive a message that the remote rejected the
>   push.

You can see how this would be useful to enforce typical work flows.

To enable direct pushing to a branch on a repo

goto

**Repo** > **Settings** > **Branch management** > **Prevent history re-writes (rebase) on these branches**

then on that page, remove the branch that you are pushing to.

This will then enable you run `git push origin +HEAD`

Then you should re-add the branch to the list to prevent random pushes to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but Bitbucket seems to be changed. In order to allow it, you should go to **Repository settings** and in WORKFLOW click on **Branch restrictions**, click to **Edit** the branch which you have tried to update and select **Allow rewriting branch history**:

[image: Allow rewriting branch history]